# getting a list using list and tuple (not using dictionary)

Tags: python-3.x

```
inp = input("Input an animal and a count, or quit to quit: ")
animalList = []

while inp != 'quit':
    val = inp.split(",")
    animalList[val[0]] = animalList.get(val[0], 0) + int(val[1])
    inp = input("Input animal and a count, or quit to quit: ")

print(animalList)
print("The total number of animal is", sum(animalList), "the average is", 
1.0 * sum(animalList) / len(animalList))
```

I want to store data in a list of tuples and add the duplicates to the already stored count. 
something like this-> 
[(cat, 9), (dog, 7)]

and get total number of animal and the average count. Print ->

animal, count
cat, 9
dog, 7

but my loop seems to be not working properly. any suggestions?

Comment: see collection.Counter class  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter

Comment: `collections.Counter` is a subclass of `dict`. @CullenDuYaw, why no dictionaries?

Comment: You need to implement your own  key lookup on the list then. @zipa shows a very straightforward  way of doing it.

Comment: thank you all. yes @zipa just showed how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid `dict` you can use something like this:

```
inp = input("Input an animal and a count, or quit to quit: ")
animals = []
count = []
while inp != 'quit':
    val = inp.split(",")
    if val[0] in animals:
        count[animals.index(val[0])] += int(val[1])
    else:
        animals.append(val[0])
        count.append(int(val[1]))
animalList = list(zip(animals, count))
print(animalList)
print("The total number of animal is", sum(count), "the average is", 
1.0 * sum(count) / len(count))
```

Or if you want to use `animalList` again:

```
print("The total number of animal is", sum([i[1] for i in animalList]), "the average is", 
1.0 * sum([i[1] for i in animalList]) / len(animalList))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just added one more line of  inp = input("Input an animal and a count, or quit to quit: ")  in the 'if' statement for looping until the user enter 'quit'.

Answer (score 0):

You could store them by the given count as well:

```
  inp = input("Input an animal and a count, or quit to quit: ")
  animalList = []

  while inp != 'quit':
      animal, count = inp.split(",")[0:2]
      animalList.extend([animal]*int(count)) # extend list with as much animals as given
      inp = input("Input animal and a count, or quit to quit: ")

  animalList.sort() # sort them together
  print(animalList) # print for debug

  for a in set(animalList): # print once for each animal
      print("The total number of animal ", a , " is ", animalList.count(a), " the average is ", float(animalList.count(a)) / len(animalList))
```

Input:

```
a,4
b,3
a,6
c,1
c,1
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
The total number of animal  a  is  10  the average is  0.6666666666666666
The total number of animal  b  is  3  the average is  0.2
The total number of animal  c  is  2  the average is  0.13333333333333333
```

Comment: thank you very much. this is one precise way to go. I appreciate all the suggestions.